# What is rootfs# and what can you do with it?

Tags: command-line, boot, arch-linux, prompt

I have been dropped to a `[rootfs /]#` prompt many times when booting my distro failed. Usually I found I couldn't fix the problem with the limited commands available, so I would use any spare Live CD I had laying around.

But what is the `rootfs` prompt? Why does it have limited commands available? And can I use it to boot my system after the problem has been fixed?

Comment: Similar on SeverFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/275988/what-is-rootfs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Rootfs` is a special instance of `ramfs` (or `tmpfs`, if that's enabled), which is
always present in `2.6 systems`.  You can't unmount rootfs.

[image]

At kernel initialization time, there is an absolutely minimal filesystem registered, called `rootfs`. The code that implements this filesystem can be found in `fs/ramfs/inode.c`, which also happens to contain the code for the `ramfs` filesystem. rootfs is basically identical to `ramfs`, except for the specification of the `MS_NOUSER` flag. This is interpreted by the routine `graft_tree` in `fs/namespace.c`, and I think it prevents userland processes doing their own mounts of `rootfs`.

The routine `init_mount_tree` (found in fs/namespace.c) is called at system startup time to mount an instance of rootfs, and make it the root namespace of the current process (*remember that, under Linux, different processes can have different filesystem namespaces*).

It contains all applications, settings, devices, data and more. Without the root file system, your Linux system can not run.

See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Comment: That was a good answer explaining the rootfs file system, and explains the limited commands available, but there is nothing about the prompt itself and what you can do with it.

Comment: @wolfo9999: I updated my answer to explain better.

Comment: You sure did :) great answer now that I can visualize it. +50 when I can award it. Says I have to wait 17 hours. Although that's enough time for someone else to make a better answer if they can.

Comment: @TiagoƇ. Really great answer that helped me a lot too! May I ask where this great graphic explanation is from? A source link would be nice ;)

Comment: @chirp look in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt =]

Comment: @TiagoƇ. I'm aware, thank you. But: Where do you have this IMAGE from? I am looking for something like this quite a while

Comment: What kind of diagram is that? What is the name of the relation between the nodes? What is an ellipse and what is a square?